# matplotlib python3.4.1 win7

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-7

I am using python3.4.1 in win7
And I wana use matplotlib.
but this error code has occured.
Could you help me?

```
>>> text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\draw\dispersion.py", line 25, in dispersion_plot

    import pylab

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>

    from matplotlib.pylab import *

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>

    import six

ImportError: No module named 'six'



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>

    text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"])

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 445, in dispersion_plot


    dispersion_plot(self, words)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\draw\dispersion.py", line 27, in dispersion_plot

    raise ValueError('The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab).'

ValueError: The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab).See 

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/
>>>
```

Comment: do you have `matplotlib` and/or `six` installed? How did you install them?

Comment: Oh sorry!The problem was already solved! I installed the numpy and matplotlib in python3.4 and [import numpy]and[import matplotlib],so they work as neat.

Comment: I'm very sorry my answer is too late and very glad to get your kindness for this noob.Looking back this question, it is so bad and poor! I must apologize and gratitude to you.